# Authentication error while trying to login to Django admin panel, cannot log out

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, admin

I have two questions, the second is related to the first and could indeed be the cause.

I am mid-development of a simple Django project, I used the (partially finished) login form to login using a non-super user. It redirected to the login page, but when I then proceded to localhost/admin, it came up with this error.

```
You are authenticated as 3rdMayTest (this is the username), but are not authorized to access this page. Would you like to login to a different account?
```

The problem being, I tried refreshing the page, clicking out of it, and restarting the server, but the error persists and I cannot figure out how to LOGOUT so I can continue.

The related issue is in the **SETTINGS.py** (for the project) file, I added this, in the hope that on submitting login form data, it would login and re-direct to the home page, but instead it causes the above error, and redirects to the login page.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'socialmedia-home'
```

socialmedia-home, is, as far as I know, the name I've given and this is in the **socialmedia app/urls.py file**

```
#THIS IS THE SOCIAL MEDIA URLS ..not the root directory URLS
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='socialmedia-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='socialmedia-about'),
    #path('login/', views.login, name='socialmedia-login'),  
]
```

My questions are:
1. Problem 2 seems to have caused this problem in some way, as the page is not redirecting properly after the login form is submitted. But on going to the localhost/admin how do I remove the error that persists?
2. How do I solve Problem 2 that is obviously causing the form not to submit correctly or redirect to the right place?

Comment: How are you including the socialmedia urls in the main urls.py file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this error is because you're logged in as a non-staff user, that does not have access to the admin. Normally, you should have a "logout" button on your home page so users can logout. If you don't have that (yet), just add it as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-out). It's a very simple view that you can then add to your urls (e.g. `path('logout/', views.logout)`).

But you can also just login in that admin login page with a user that has staff privileges (your superuser for example) and that will automatically logout your non-staff user and log you in as staff. And the admin has a 'logout' link.

Problem 2: the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is used by the default `LoginView` provided by django.contrib.auth. Is your custom `login` view doing something with it?

Comment: Er I know what the problem is...my whole point is that it isn't allowing me to login as anyone else. It repeats that error on trying to login as superuser.

Comment: Remove the cookie with the session id from your browser. And check in your shell if the user you think is super user really is.

Comment: For some reason, my previous superuser had not been added to the database, so you were right. Thanks for trouble shooting. (and removing the cookie with the session id (clearing cache and forms) worked. Thanks!

Comment: I meant using the superuser credentials should always work, so I said check if the user you think is superuser really is.